# Can we start a section (UITableView) to a section number?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Can we start a section (UITableView) to a section number?

For example I want to start to section 3?

Comment: What do you mean by "to start"? Do you mean "positioning the table in such a way that section 3 is at the top of the view"?

Comment: What do you mean by start? As in you want to scroll to section 3 or the table view must never ask for sections less than 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to position the rows of the table in such a way that a particular section is at the top of the view, do this:

```
UITableView *tableView; // <<== This is your table view
...
NSInteger desiredSection = 3;
NSIndexPath *scrollTo = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:desiredSection];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollTo
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                  animated:YES]; // <<== Use NO if you do not want animation
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It's just what I wanted !